# How do I change the background url in javascript after using background-size: cover?

Tags: javascript, css, background, cover

This is the CSS part (using background-size: cover):

```css
#container>div {
  background: url("../static/opti2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

What I want to do is change the **URL background** using Javascript.

Comment: Use `background-image` but camelCased when referenced from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment above, use this code, replacing the URL with the new URL.

```js
<script>

document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundImage = "url(..static/opti22.jpg)";

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Matthew M.  

in my case, it`s a little different because it is not just a URL of the element is a #container>div

Comment: In that case, use `document.querySelector('#container>div').style.backgroundImage = 'url(..static.opti22.jpg';`.